# How to get login user's groups list using XMPP?

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, multiuserchat

I am developing MUC using XMPP framework. I created groups. When the user uninstalls the app and then re-installs it, I want to get all of that user's groups list. I am doing the following to get groups list. Sometimes it returns groups list but sometimes it doesn't.

Configure XMPPMUC

```
var xmppMuc = XMPPMUC()
xmppMuc = XMPPMUC.init(dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
xmppMuc.activate(xmppStream)
self.xmppMuc.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
```

Call discover rooms of XMPPMUC

```
self.xmppMuc.discoverRooms(forServiceNamed:"conference.app.net")
```

And the below delegate method of XMPPMUC is also called but sometimes it returns an empty list.

```
func xmppMUC(_ sender: XMPPMUC, didDiscoverRooms rooms: [Any], forServiceNamed serviceName: String) {
    print("MUC : didDiscoverRooms : \(rooms)")
    print("MUC : forServiceNamed : \(serviceName)\n")
}
```

I want the list of all user's groups.